# Router to router setup works fine with straight cable up to 2-3 meter it is not working for 45 meter why?

Tags: router, setup

FIrst router(TPLINK) is connceted with ADSL Modem, and second router is connected via 49 meter cat-6 cable with straight connection, it is not working, but connection between two routers using patch cord (up to 3 mtrs) is very fine, what is the solutions

Answer (score 2):

The length of your cable suggests a custom-made length.

I recommend replacing the RJ-45 connectors on both sides, wired to [TIA/EIA 568](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568#Wiring) specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question by saying the 3 meter cord works, but the 49 meter one does not. This indicates the problem is with the Ethernet cable.

Test the 49 meter cord and you will likely find it is defective. Ethernet cable testers are easy to find and use.

[image]

Comment: I'd add that people should beware that the kind of dumb tester pictured only tells you if you have the correct pinout. It can't tell if you got the twisted pair pairings right, and those pairings are critical for the noise cancellation that becomes critical at longer lengths. The pairings are 1&2, 3&6 (6, not 4), 4&5 (5, not 3), 7&8.